# Create a dictionary with arrays as values

Tags: c#, dictionary

I'm trying to initialize a dictionary with string elements as keys and int[] elements as values, as follows:

```
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,int[]> myDictionary;
myDictionary = new Dictionary<string,int[]>{{"length",{1,1}},{"width",{1,1}}};
```

But the debugger keeps saying: "Unexpected symbol '{'".

Could you tell me what's wrong with the above code?

Thank you!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I am not sure for c# but the following works in Java for example:

instead of

```
{1,1}
```

try

```
new int[]{1,1}
```

or

```
new[]{1,1}
```

Comment: Or simply `new[] {1,1}` if you prefer.

Comment: For anybody who is curious and wants more info, as I did, try here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/

Answer (score 9):

Below are two examples that work. The second example only works inside a method. The first example will work inside a method or outside a method in a class.

The initial code was missing the () for the new Dictionary() statement which is probably what gave the "{" unexepcted symbol error. The "new Int[]" is also required

```
class SomeClass
{
    Dictionary<string, int[]> myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, int[]>()
    {
        {"length", new int[] {1,1} },
        {"width", new int[] {1,1} },
    };

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        Dictionary<string, int[]> myDictionary2;
        myDictionary2 = new Dictionary<string, int[]>()
        {
            {"length", new int[] {1,1} },
            {"width", new int[] {1,1} },
        };

    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,int[]> myDictionary;
        myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, int[]> { { "length", new int[] { 1, 1 } }, { "width", new int[] { 1, 1 } } };
```

Answer (score 5):

You will need to specify that it's an array that you are inserting in to your Dictionary:

```
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, int[]> myDictionary;
myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, int[]> {{"length", new int[]{1,2}},{ "width",new int[]{3,4}}};
```

Answer (score 4):

In addition to all good answers you can also try this.

```
Dictionary<string, List<int>> dict = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>();
```

If possible prefer List<> over arrays as resizing is difficult in Arrays. You can not delete an element from an array. But an element can be deleted from List.